# How to remove Widget.Material3.TabLayout bottom divider

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout, material-components-android, material3

For a style using the `Widget.Material3.TabLayout`

```
<style name="MyTabLayout" parent="Widget.Material3.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorFullWidth">true</item>
</style>
```

[image]

how does one remove the gray bottom divider that is contiguous to the indicator,

[image]

such that only the blue indicator is visible?

Comment: According to the Material XMLs, that gray line is defined in `m3_tabs_background.xml` and has the colour `colorSurfaceVariant`.

You may either override `android:background` on the `TabLayout` XML or change  `colorSurfaceVariant` for that component using theming.

Comment: @PaulW you are right. I've used background approach in my case